# Can't install xfburn, unable to locate package

Tags: software-installation, sudo

when i try to install `xfburn` it comes with this message:

[image: error message]

It says, it is unable to locate package xfburn

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: [`xfburn` is in Universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xfburn). Enable it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

`xfburn` is located in the `universe` repository, which might not be enabled by default on your installation.

To enable it, simply run

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then update your software index lists using

```
sudo apt update
```

Now finally you can install your application by typing

```
sudo apt install xfburn
```